# Referring to rows and columns difference

Tags: excel, vba

Second line leads to an error. Are Rows and Columns differs that much or it is just my system problem?

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows("1:5").Select

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("1:5").Select
```

Update: what is the best alternative for second line?

Comment: Dont have columns letters (chars) to name them?

Comment: They do but I need to be relative.

Comment: If the `UsedRange` doesn't have 5 columns, this will error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(,5).Select
```

Comment: That is do the job. Any idea if .Columns("1:5") not valid due to flaw or there is some logic behind it?

Comment: They did it to eliminate ambiguity. Both Rows and Columns return a Range.o object.  Range("1:1")  refers to the Rows and Range("A:E") refers to Columns.  Sorry for the short answer.  I'm posting from my phone.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the explanation. My mistake was that I was sure that .columns(“A:B”) is global reference and even within .usedrange will refer to columns A and B. I don’t even had an idea to try it out. Now all clear, thanks again.